# Updating widget value on render?

Tags: flutter, render

I have a Flutter app, and I want to display a color depending on the current system time in milliseconds since epoch. Of course, I cant refresh the state of the widget several times a second to change the color. But how can I achieve this effect? Is there some kind of render-method I can override?

P.S.: I am using a `Material` widget to display the color.

Comment: "Of course, I cant refresh the state of the widget several times a second to change the color" why not? To change the color the widget needs to rerender, to rerender you call `setState()`. I guess you are looking for https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html

Comment: So it is okay to rebuild state several times a second? Okay. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yeah there's nothing wrong with tons of setState. You may want to wrap your timer into a RepaintBoundary though

Comment: Flutter updates the view only when a new frame is due, no matter how often you called `setState()` since the last frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter updates the view only when a new frame is due, no matter how often you called `setState()` since the last frame.